# SetPin return false on android but no exception

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

When I try to use SetPin on a bluetooth device it returns false. but according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html if it returns false it should display an error. Any ideas? my code is down here.

```
   pin = (byte[]) BluetoothDevice.class.getMethod("convertPinToBytes", String.class).invoke(BluetoothDevice.class, "4711");
            boolean check = CurrentDevice.setPin(pin);
            CurrentDevice.setPairingConfirmation(false);
            CurrentDevice.createBond();
            CurrentDevice.getClass().getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput").invoke(CurrentDevice);
            int test = CurrentDevice.getBondState();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#setPin(byte[]):

```
public boolean setPin(byte<> pin)
```

> > **Returns:**
> >     true pin has been set false for error

There is no mention of an exception and so if you are not getting one your code is behaving correctly.